# MySQL not inserting using PDO and Stored Procs

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, pdo, innodb

I'm using PDO and stored procedures with MySQL (InnoDB) and for some reason data isn't being inserted - sort of.

When I view the properties on the table the Auto_increment is going up each time I run it and it's going through without errors.  At the end, I'm selecting the variables I'm passing in and it's all good.

However, even with the table "incrementing", the data is not there.  If I select on what it says the auto_increment ID is, I get nothing.  If I select * and order desc, again, it doesn't show the latest.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Thanks!

Here's the Stored Proc:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `DB`$$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `addVal`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`data`@`%` PROCEDURE `addVal`(

        v_val_accountid INT,
        v_val_groupid INT,
        v_val_validationtypeid INT,
        v_val_validationstatusid INT,
        v_val_key VARCHAR(255),
        v_val_expirationdate DATETIME

)
MAIN:BEGIN

        INSERT `Validation` (
            Val_AccountId,
            Val_GroupId,
            Val_ValidationTypeId,
            Val_ValidationStatusId,
            Val_Key,
            Val_ExpirationDate

        ) VALUES (
            v_val_accountid,
            v_val_groupid,
            v_val_validationtypeid,
            v_val_validationstatusid,
            v_val_key,
            v_val_expirationdate
        );

END$$

DELIMITER;
```

Here's the PDO prepared statement:

```
    $key = '123456789';
    $group_id = 0;
    $type_id = 2;
    $status_id = 1;
    $date = 'DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)';

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("CALL addVal(:account_id, :group_id, :type_id, :status_id, :key, :date)");

    $stmt->bindParam(':account_id', $account_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':group_id', $group_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':type_id', $type_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':status_id', $status_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $stmt->bindParam(':key', $key, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Comment: I think you will need to show some code and examples

Comment: Hmm. So the data that you enter into the query through PDO is missing? Are you sure it is there in the first place?

Comment: The data is passed correctly into the stored proc and I can select what I'm passing in, and it's showing everything.  If I select LAST_INSERT_ID(), it increments - it seems like it's working.  But, the data is just not there when I open the table.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting some kind of error in the stored procedure because `DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)` is a function, not string so you should not assign it as PDO::PARAM_STR.

You can probably change that part to something like:

```
// REPLACE PARAMETER FROM PARAM TO ACTUAL DATA_ADD FUNCTION
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("CALL addVal(:account_id, :group_id, :type_id, :status_id, :key, DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))");

...

// COMMENT OUT BINDING
//    $stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);
```

Hope this help!

Comment: Thanks, tried this, still doesn't work.  I inserted a new record to the table manually and the auto incremented column, jumped from 5519 to 5540, all the numbers in between are from what I've been doing here.  It's incrementing - but there's no actual records.

Comment: that sounds like the transaction isn't committed when you do from php.  what does it do after `$stmt->bindParam(':date', $date, PDO::PARAM_STR);`? Do you run actual `$stmt->execute();` ? If you have the execute already, is php or mysql configured to auto commit?